# A decent, low-cost color printer for Windows XP that is not inkjet?

Tags: windows-xp, printer

Ok, maybe it can be inkjet, if you know one without the problems that inkjet normally has?

1. Expensive per-page cost for color cartridges
2. Delicate print heads
3. Alignment problems
4. Short printer life

I'm looking for a 4 to 10 cent per page cost or thereabouts.  If lasers exist that won't break the bank, that would be really cool.  I don't care about printing photos, but I do need color graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Canon Pixma iP3600

Comment: Looks promising.  Cartridges $14 for a set from Amazon.  Do you own one?  Do you like it?

Comment: Ouch.  50 bucks for genuine Canon cartridges.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - Yes. I also had an older similar model, iP3300 - worked flawlessly for, (?) hard to say, two maybe three years.

Comment: Mind you, I do print relatively a lot, ~1000 pages/monthly.

Comment: All replacable cartridges, of course :)